# QGIS Profile from Line tool requiring shapely.wkd?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I am trying to install the Profile from Line tool for QGIS, and the system informed me I need shapely.wkd. A search on the QGIS site for shapely takes me to the Contour Plugin...can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: What OS are you using? Your QGIS version, too.

Comment: Mac OSX, QGIS 1.8.0. I am running in to a whole string of things I have needed to install, matplotlib, shapely, updated python. I am still having trouble installing the profile from line and contour plugins though. Do I need to install Matplotlib and Shapely in to the QGIS python module files?

Comment: Problem seems to be due to incompatibility between versions so installing won't work. Somebody correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Oh okay. Is there perhaps a workaround for this, or am I to wait for the issue to be fixed. This is the one issue preventing me from using QGIS full time, now I have to switch to a different mapping program to construct elevation profiles. Not that big of a deal, but it would be convenient if it worked on QGIS.

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't know any workarounds right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be broken, at least for OS X according to the [QGIS mailing list](http://osgeo-org.1560.n6.nabble.com/Problem-installing-Profile-plugin-td5007211.html).

> Profile tool is a plugin affected by an incompatibility of PyQwt5 with
>   recent PyQt versions.  It needs to be fixed to use another graphing
>   toolbox like Matplotlib.  Until then it will be broken in the current
>   QGIS.

Still broken as of Oct 11. Not sure if it's fixed now.